# Set Theory : Percentage of students who did not pass in any of the subjects

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$880$ students appeared in an exam, $224$ passed in Physics, $240$ passed in Chemistry and $336$ passed in Math and $64$ passed in Chemistry and Math, $80$ passed in physics and Math, $40$ passed in Physics and Chemistry and $24$ passed in all three.
What is the percentage of students who did not pass in any of the subjects?

My Approach :--

Using $3-sets$ Venn Diagram :-

Total students $= 880$

Passed in (Physics $\cap$ Chemistry $\cap$ Math) = 24

Passed in (Physics $\cap$ Chemistry) $= 40 -24 = 16$

Passed in (Physics $\cap$ Math) $= 80-24 = 56$

Passed in (Math $\cap$ Chemistry) $= 64-24 = 40$

Passed in Physics $= 128$

Passed in Math $= 216$

Passed in Chemistry $= 160$

Total number of students passed $= 640$

Total number of students failed $= 240$

My doubt is how to figure out the number of students who have failed in all the $3$ subjects in order to answer the question asked ?

Doesn't the question asked means that "% of students who failed in all the 3 subjects" ?

Please help !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think this should be solvable by the inclusion exclusion principle

Comment: @andrew : can you please put down your solution? Also if let's say number of students passed in (Physics $\cap$ Math) $= 80-24 = 56$ , then does it mean that exactly these $56$ students have failed only in Chemistry ?

Comment: When you say "students passed in (Physics $\cap$ Maths) you really mean (Physics $\cap$ Maths$\cap$¬Chemistry), you've been told by the question that (Physics $\cap$ Maths)=80. So yes, 56 is the number of students who have failed only Chemistry.

Comment: ok...yeah i mean what you mentioned...then is there a way we can get the number of students who failed in all the three subjects out of total 240 students who failed ?

Comment: Like I said in my original comment take a look at the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html)

Comment: $240$ is the number of students who have failed. $640$ is the total number of students who have passed, and students can only pass or fail, so you just have $880 - 640 = 240$.

Answer (score 1):

$240$ is the number of students who have failed. Therefore the percentage of students who have failed is $\frac{240}{840} = \frac{2}{7}$ or around $28.6 \%$.

Comment: but out of those 240 there could be ones who did not pass in any one of the subjects, there could be ones who did not pass in exactly two of the subjects and there could be ones who did not pass in any of the three subjects i.e. failed in all the three subjects? i think the question is asking about the last part.

Comment: You have covered all these cases by the principle of exclusion-inclusion. See [this diagram](https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/embedded_uploads/Screen-Shot-2016-01-12-16-37-12.png?width=2400) from Brilliant. The region you are looking for is outside all the three circles, and not the outside region plus the region with only A.